# How do I set a cookie for the entire domain name?

Tags: javascript, function, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to set a cookie that would work through my entire domain:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

So I did this:

`document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+expires+"; path=/";` it's still not setting it for the entire domain.

And this:

`document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/; domain=.mysite.com";` still nothing.

What is the problem and how would I set it for an entire domain name? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Try taking off the first `.` on the domain in your last attempt

Comment: I am so confused. Nothing seems to be working. I try with / without the `.`. Everything works for the same page, but not the entire domain.

Comment: No, I was saying to try `document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/; domain=mysite.com";`

Comment: Not working. I tried.

Comment: according to documentation `domain=mysite.com` should work. Check in your browser (developer tools) to see what your site is sending in headers to set the cookie